# botão para voltar para inicio da pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Boa tarde, estou fazendo um projeto e criei um botão para voltar ao início da pagina, porém este não aparece quando solicitado. Já vi vídeos aulas, inúmeros tutorias e nada. Gostaria de ajuda.
 Meu código está da seguinte forma:

```js
/* BOTÃO PARA VOLTAR AO INÍCIO */
$(document).ready (function(){
    var divBotao=$('.botaoVoltar');
    var linkBotao=$('.botaoVoltar-Link');

    /* Mostrar botão*/

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop()>70){
            divBotao.fadeIn();
        }else{
            divBotao.fadeOut(); 
        }

    });

    /* Clicar e voltar ao topo*/

    divBotao.click(function(){

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},800);

        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.botaoVoltar{
    position:fixed;
    float:right;
    margin-left:900px;
    margin-top:400px;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:none;
}

.botaoVoltar-Link{
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    line-height:50px;
    color: black;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="botaoVoltar">
    <a class="botaoVoltar-Link " href="">Voltar a topo</a>
</div>
```

Importei a biblioteca jQuery.
   Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Seu script funciona, o que está faltando é vc colocar alguma altura no body, coloca ai o height do body em 200vh que vai gerar scoll na janela e o botão vai aparecer

Comment: Coloquei, porém não resolveu

Comment: Publiquei a resposta veja o que deixei lá descrito, vai te ajudar

Comment: Modifiquei a parte do margin e coloquei left e bottom no lugar. O problema foi a ligação com a página, pois tanto o jQuery quanto o javaScript eram externos. Porém o problema foi que primeiro eu chamei javaScript ao invés do jQuery primeiro, por isso o botão sumiu e não apareceu mais. Obrigada pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O elemento com `position: fixed` necessita obrigatoriamente de uma propriedade `top` ou `bottom`, se não ele fica sem a referência da janela do navegador. Como as propriedades `top` e `bottom` de todo elemento tem como padrão o valor `auto`, o elemento fixo não tem como saber onde ele ficará fixo em relação ao topo ou à borda de baixo da janela, fazendo com que o elemento acompanhe o flow dos elementos e fique fora da janela quando o conteúdo da página excede a altura da janela. Ou seja, o código até funciona, mas quando o botão recebe o `.fadeIn()`, ele não ficará visível pois estará fora da área visível da janela, e na prática, o elemento não está fixo.

Então, no seu caso, basta colocar uma propriedade `top: 0` na div onde está o botão. Porém, não faz muito sentido usar `margins` em elemento fixo, basta você usar `top` (ou `bottom`) e `left` (ou `right`) para deixar o botão onde quer.

No seu caso, bastaria um `left: 900px` e um `top: 40px;` no lugar de `margin-left: 900px` e `margin-top: 40px` (coloquei abaixo `left: 90px` como exemplo porque a janela do snippet é pequena e com `left: 900px` o botão iria ficar fora da área do snippet):

> Outra coisa é que a propriedade `float` não deve ser usada em
>   elementos fixos, até porque não faz nenhum efeito. Se o elemento deve
>   fixar fixo, não faz sentido usar `float`. Se quiser que o elemento
>   fique à direita, use `right`.

```js
/* BOTÃO PARA VOLTAR AO INÍCIO */
$(document).ready (function(){
    var divBotao=$('.botaoVoltar');
    var linkBotao=$('.botaoVoltar-Link');

    /* Mostrar botão*/

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop()>70){
            divBotao.fadeIn();
        }else{
           divBotao.fadeOut(); 
        }

    });

    /* Clicar e voltar ao topo*/

    divBotao.click(function(){

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},800);

        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.botaoVoltar{
    position:fixed;
    left:90px;
    top:40px;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:none;
}

.botaoVoltar-Link{
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    line-height:50px;
    color: black;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="botaoVoltar">
    <a class="botaoVoltar-Link" href="">Voltar a topo</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Modifiquei a parte do margin e coloquei left e bottom no lugar. O problema foi a ligação com a página, pois tanto o jQuery quanto o javaScript eram externos. 
Porém o problema foi que primeiro eu chamei javaScript ao invés do jQuery primeiro, por isso o botão sumiu e não apareceu mais. Obrigada pela ajuda.